# UIScrollView weird behavior with UITextField/UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uipickerview

So I'm pretty puzzled right now because my UIScrollView is acting pretty weirdly.

Basically, I have a UIScrollView that is about twice the height of an iPhone 6 that I am using to display some graphs using iOS Charts and so I've set it to be able to scroll and bounce vertically, but neither scroll nor bounce horizontally. All of the graphs, and some additional UITextFields and UILabels are embedded on a separate "body view" that is aligned with the frame of the UIScrollView as seems to be common practice. Thus, the hierarchy of my views looks like this:

[image: hierarchy]

This worked well until I noticed today that when I press a specific UITextField on this UIScrollView, which triggers a UIPickerView, all of the sudden my scroll view starts to allow horizontal bouncing. This behavior does not occur for the two other UITextField's on the body view when they are tapped.

I've checked all of the code that is being triggered by tapping on the affected text field, and nothing is directly editing the frames or bounds of any UI objects. In fact, the only function called when the text field is tapped on is the `textFieldDidBeginEditing`. I've attached the code for this function below, but I am fairly certain it is not the problem.

My next suspicion was that the UIPickerView popping up has been messing with the dimensions of my scroll view and/or it's embedded view. I'm not quite sure if this is possible/probable, but this whole thing has left me pretty stumped.

Here's my code:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    if textField == overallTimeframeTextField {
        ...
        // Not the problematic text field
    } else if textField == subjectTimeframeTextField {
        ...
        // Also not the problematic text field
    } else { // Affected text field
        
        // Set the text of the text field
        if textField.text == "" {
            // This is executed in this scenario
            textField.text = subjectPickerData[0]
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a short GIF outlining my issue. You can see me scrolling down the page, where I am not able to bounce horizontally, and then once I tag on the text field, all of the sudden the scroll view allows the bounces.

[GIF](http://gph.is/2eNp92A)

I'm pretty lost with this issue, so any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

To clarify, I explicitly declare my scrollView's content size to be equal the desired height and the width of the screen that the user is on. I then set the bodyView's width to equal the same value. This is done in `viewDidAppear` with the following code:

```
// Fit the content to the screen
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 1200)
bodyView.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
```

I also have constraints which force the scrollview and body view to both have the same width as the UIViewController's default child view (the parent of the scroll view in my hierarchy).

One interesting thing that I've noticed is that when I print the width of my scroll view and my body view when the views load, I receive the following output for iPhone 6:

> 385.0
>
> 385.0

This is correct as that is the width of an iPhone 6. However, when I tap on the text field, and then print the same values, I get this output:

> 385.0
>
> 384.0

So for some reason, my body view is one point smaller than my scroll view. I've tried setting the body view's width to be equal to the scroll view when I tap on the text field, like I do in the `viewDidAppear` function, but this had no effect.

In terms of the UIPickerView, I initialize a pickerview with my class instance variables like so:

```
var subjectPickerView = UIPickerView()
```

I then assign this picker view to be the input view for the text field in `viewDidLoad`:

```
textField.inputView = subjectPickerView
```

So I'm not sure if this makes the picker view a subview of the scroll view, but it's just replacing the keyboard in this scenario.

Comment: is your scrollview bounce Vertically is enabled ?

Comment: @CodeChanger Yes, `bounces` and `bounces vertically` are enabled and `bounces horizontally` is not enabled.

Comment: *"I've set it to ... neither scroll nor bounce horizontally"* The ability to scroll is based on the `contentSize` --- are you setting that explicitly or with constraints? And you say *"UITextField --- which triggers a UIPickerView"* How are you displaying the Picker View? Is it a subview of the scroll view?

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for the comment. I've updated my post to include additional information regarding your questions.

Comment: Did you use auto layout like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531794/4884119 answer, or you just code it in swift? I think you forget to set the space

Comment: @AchmadJP Thanks for that resource. That helped me figure out the source of my problem. I have now posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AchmadJP's comment, I tried explicitly creating an equal widths constraint between my scroll view and my body view. This seems to have solved the issue.

The reason I had not done this previously was that the body view's leading space, trailing space, top space and bottom space were constrained to be the same as those of the scroll view. Theoretically, this should have meant that the widths were equal at all times, but apparently, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the same problem, you can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32531794/4884119) for the solution.